# 'list' object is not callable while trying to make a board

Tags: python

I want to make a board where I will enter my numbers. I have this code:

```
def board(size):
    sqlist = []
    for i in range(size):
        sqlist.append(0) 
    return sqlist

board(5)
array = []
elements = array(5)
components = int(input("Δώσε αριθμό"))
for a in range[5]:
    components = a.insert
    list = components
    if max > x:
        print max
    if min < x:
        print min

print sqlist
```

but it returns this error

> 'list' object is not callable

Comment: For the love of God, please fix your code formatting.

Comment: Your code is not formatted correctly making it impossible to read, but I do notice that `array` is a list and you try to call it `array(5)`. Perhaps you meant to grab the item at index 5 `array[5]`?  (Note the square brackets.)

Comment: There are several lines in your code that don't do anything close to what you think they do. You might want to review whatever instructional materials you're using.

Comment: What is `elements = array(5)` supposed to do? Putting `(5)` after a name means to call the function with `5` as an argument. But `array` is a list, not a function.

Comment: Conversely, `range[5]` should be `range(5)`, since `range` is the name of a function, not a list.

Comment: You call `board(5)`, which returns a list. But you don't assign the returned value to a variable.